# pandas operation combining each two rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, apply

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
from uncertainties import ufloat # pip3 uncertainties.py 
import random
random.seed(0)
values = [[round(random.random(),2) for i in range(3)] for j in range(4)]
df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=['name1','sd', 'name2', 'sd'], columns=['A','B','C'])
```

and I want to rearrange the data, where I combine the mean and sd into one row, as ufloat, of which the desired output looks as follows:

```
new_values = [[ufloat(0.91,0.90), ufloat(0.98,0.31), ufloat(0.81,0.73)],
             [ufloat(0.90,0.10), ufloat(0.68,0.43), ufloat(0.47, 0.61)]]
df = pd.DataFrame(new_values, index=['name1', 'name2'], columns=['A','B','C'])
```

I think it might be easiest to create two dataframes and combine them somehow

```
mean = df.iloc[::2].reset_index()
std  = df.iloc[1::2].reset_index()
```

where now I need to merge the two and apply ufloat

Answer (score 1):

This is my current solution:

```
mean = df.iloc[::2]
std  = df.iloc[1::2]
tmp = np.array([ufloat(x[0], x[1]) for x 
               in zip(mean.values.ravel(), std.values.ravel())])
df = pd.DataFrame(tmp.reshape(mean.shape), columns=mean.columns, index=mean.index)
```